Sequentially Processing and Storing Sensor Data Before Sending Event Messages in Apache Spark Structured Streaming
I am developing a data processing framework using Apache Spark's Structured Streaming, where I'm confronted with the challenge of managing the processing sequence of different types of messages within a single micro-batch. My objective is to ensure all sensor data messages are processed and stored before any event messages are forwarded to a subsequent application for further processing.
Background:
The system architecture includes two principal applications:

Data Ingestion Application: This application processes messages from a single Kafka topic, which are categorized into sensor data messages and event messages. Both types of messages are present within each micro-batch. The application's essential function is to persist all sensor data messages into a time-series database promptly. It deals with a continuous stream of sensor data messages, coming in every minute, and sporadic event data messages, which mark significant milestones like the completion of a process.
Event Handling Application: Post the ingestion and storage of sensor data, this application processes event messages, which are sent from the first application via a different Kafka topic. It's critical for the operation of this application that it only processes event messages after ensuring all preceding sensor data has been fully ingested and stored by the first application.

Challenge:
The primary challenge is to devise a mechanism within the first application that ensures every sensor data message within a micro-batch is completely processed and stored before any event message from the same batch is forwarded to the second application. This sequencing is crucial to ensure the integrity and completeness of the data processing workflow, particularly for the event handling that depends on the complete dataset of sensor data.
Attempted Solutions:
I have explored utilizing the DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch() API in an effort to separate and sequentially process the sensor data and event messages within each batch. The goal is to finalize the handling of all sensor data messages before initiating the transmission of event messages to the second application. However, finding a reliable method to enforce this sequence has proven challenging.
Question:
How can I implement a solution in Apache Spark Structured Streaming that ensures the complete processing and storage of all sensor data messages before any event messages are sent to the next stage in the workflow? Are there specific strategies or features within Structured Streaming that facilitate this type of controlled sequential processing? Any guidance, experiences, or pointers to similar problems would be greatly appreciated.
